# javascript & php interaction - what are the options?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The short question: 
What is the best way to implement javascript client-side scripts that need to interact with php code on the server-side?

The long question:
This is a question seeking opinions on a suitable infrastructure for a browser-based multiplayer turn-based war game.

I've already written such a game that runs entirely server side using PHP with an SQL database. It works, but it's a bit clunky because each time a player makes a move the whole web page must be refreshed. Consequently I'd like to move some of the processing to client side in javascript.

I want all of the game decisions to be taken on the server so it's the interaction between the javascript running in player's browser and the PHP running on the server that I am asking about.

For example, Suppose it's Player A's turn and he's looking at the current game map in his browser. 
He "commands" an army to move north with a button click. 
The command is relayed up to the server.
The server determines the outcome of the command and sends the results back to the browser.
The browser javascript updates the map and reports the results to the player, possibly with some groovy and badly-drawn graphics.

I'm pretty sure I can achieve what I want with Ajax with GET/POST requests to the server, perhaps using the jQuery library to encapsulate the calls.
Is this the best approach?
What are the alternatives (browser compatibility is important)?
How would you do it?

I don't need a detailed design. I just need to know that my approach is vaguely sane!

Comment: It's usually done with ajax or by just echoing out the PHP to javascript variables.

Comment: Depends on what you need. AJAX is the most common way, and it covers the needs for dynamically loaded content (articles, notes, combo lists, ...). Another alternative is to write Javascript code with PHP, which can be done in the page on in a separate script file sending the `Content-Type: application/javascript` header. This is when you just need the data when the page loads. Or you can resort to [server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) or WebSockets if you need continuos feed from the server.

Comment: Especially when browser compatibility is important you should use jQuery. I'd recommend a javascript MVC library like **angularJs** as well. It will help you alot of scripting a game with javascript.

Comment: You may consider to use [backboneJS](http://backbonejs.org/). However for minimum impact on PHP service and Logic you simple prevent the default behavior (link and form submit) with jQuery to perform the same HTTP request **async** instead **sync**

Comment: Wow. Many thanks for all the quick and helpful replies. I don't need continuous data from the server and I think I can arrange it so all client-server interaction is instigated by the client-side so Ajax via jQuery would seem to be the way forward. All I need to do now is learn how to use them! I'll leave those other suggested libraries for another day. My head is already very full of javascript-related stuff. 

Thanks again, 
Ian